# Facebook posting with link param failing on first try

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to Facebook using Graph API and one of the parameters on that is link.

Example URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=Xxxx&message=&link=http://something/token/123456B&description=test

Every time the link changes the posting fails the first time. If I retry twice or thrice the call works.

Here is the error I am getting :

{"error":{"message":"Call to a member function getImageInfo() on a non-object","type":"BadMethodCallException"}}

This used to work just fine but suddenly stopped working 2 days ago.
The link always changes for us and such its breaking all the posts.

Did anything change with the API recently with Facebook ? Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

well i fixed...i think...
in the url link, the meta og:image it can't be empty as '' and the link must be absolute. if the link don't have an image, don't put the meta. by the way i update the app at the fb app panel to February 2013 Breaking Changes to activate.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in iOS development, response from server:

```
"com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 500;
    "com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     {
        body =         {
            error =             {
                message = "Call to a member function getImageInfo() on a non-object";
                type = BadMethodCallException;
            };
        };
        code = 500;
    };
```

How can help? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just managed to fix it.
Was an issue with the og:image element in the page header of the URL.
My image link was relative to the website but I changed it to absolute and all seems to work now.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{should be absolute url here}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be up and down today. It is fine sometimes, but most of the time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Facebook backend error message issue. You should consider reporting this error message and behavior at [Facebook Developers Bug Reporting System](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create)